# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 6

Tags: php, foreach

I tried to display the source code with line number.
But i am getting

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  on line 6

```
$lines= file_get_contents("http://sitename.com");

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Just a guess `$lines = json_decode($lines);`

Comment: are you getting data in $lines. do a print_r

Comment: $lines is neither an object nor array, therefore you can't iterate over it with foreach. Convert it properly. If you don't know what's inside, use `var_dump($lines)`

Comment: if(is_array($lines)){foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){//your logic}}
Add a check if $line is an array

Comment: `file_get_contents` reads file into `string`, not `array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*file_get_contents* returns a string, not an iterable, you have first to convert it to an array for example.

```
<?php
$lines= file_get_contents("http://sitename.com");
$lines = explode("\n", $lines);

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
}

?>
```